# Dialogs won't close on Android Chrome

Tags: bug, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

[image]

I noticed this evening some weirdness in the nav bar UI when accessing the site on my Android phone via Chrome.  When I open a dialog, I cannot close it by clicking outside the bounds of that dialog.  In addition, opening another dialog also doesn't close dialogs previously opened, resulting in what you see above.

I periodically see things like this happening with SO with my Android, but I just wanted to point this out.